# Most efficient way of producing constrained pairs of combinations out of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, combinations, combinatorics

I need to iterate through pairs `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` of combinations of length 2, out of a list `l` of items, with the following constraints:

1. no repetitions in pairs: if `(a, b)` already appeared, then `(b, a)` shall not be produced
2. no repetitions between pairs, i.e., pairs must be considered only once: if `(a, b)`, `(c, d)` already appeared, then `(c, d)`, `(a, b)` shall not be produced
3. the items in the two pairs must be different: `a != c and a != d and b != c and b != d`

For example, with

`l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

The pairs should be:

```
(0, 1), (2, 3)
(0, 1), (2, 4)
(0, 1), (3, 4)

(0, 2), (1, 3)
(0, 2), (1, 4)
(0, 2), (3, 4)

(0, 3), (1, 2)
(0, 3), (1, 4)
(0, 3), (2, 4)

(0, 4), (1, 2)
(0, 4), (1, 3)
(0, 4), (2, 3)

(1, 2), (3, 4)
(1, 3), (2, 4)
(1, 4), (2, 3)
```

I used integers in the example, however, I am interested in a more general-purpose solution (though the items are lists, in my specific case).

This is the solution I came up with:

```py
import itertools

used = set()

for (a, b) in itertools.combinations(l, 2):
    used.add((a, b))
    for (c, d) in itertools.combinations(l, 2):
        if a == c or a == d or b == c or b == d:
            continue
        if (c, d) in used:
            continue
        # do stuff...
        pass
```

Apart from looking cumbersome, this solution requires the additional set `used`. In the actual implementation I used `enumerate(l)` instead of `l` and put the indexes of the items in the tuples in the set, and tried to use the indexes to filter the options sooner... but did not manage to make it any better.

How can I make it more efficient and, possibly, more elegant/Pythonic?

Comment: Number 4 does not appear in your list `l`. Is this correct?

Comment: No, it was not, i just fixed it, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

An idea could be to first generate all combination of tuples and then to filter them:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
aa = list(itertools.combinations(list(itertools.combinations(l, 2)), 2))
[(a,b) for a,b in aa if set(a).isdisjoint(b)]
```

Comment: I like this approach, and voted it because it's new for me. However, it requires allocating two lists and `aa` can get huge pretty quickly, so I am not convinced it is more efficient in memory. Am I right? Is it faster instead?

Comment: Indeed, memory consumption can be a problem if L is big. Another option is to make a double loop on list(itertools.combinations(l, 2), but I don't know how to remove ((c,d), (a,b)) when  ((a,b), (c,d)) is already present.  If someone can build something with that: [(a,b) for a in aa for b in aa if set(a).isdisjoint(b)] where aa = list(itertools.combinations(l, 2). aa is much smaller in this case.